# how to integrate Oauth 2.0 with google dialogflow API

Tags: python-3.x, dialogflow-es

```
import dialogflow_v2
import os
import json
import requests
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'dummy-project-296210-e84160a72c28.json'

agent = json.dumps({"displayName":"Agent1","timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata"})

project_id = "dummy-project-296210"

url = "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{}/agent".format(project_id)

response = requests.post(url, data=agent, headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

I'm using API endpoints to fetch the details for my created agent but,How can I use google Oauth and initiate my dialogflow process to access user data to proceed further. for testing purposes I have added my own gmail account.

Comment: Are you looking for OAuth 2.0 authentication to Dialogflow API? If this is aim it worth to start with a general [concept](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user) containing the typical implementation [example](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#end_user_authentication_example) in Python  which can be also relevant for Dialogflow API. Having any other concerns just expand the expectations in the initial question.

Comment: Consider also edit and hide some user sensitive/private information in your code example, mitigating the risk of unexpected event.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for the help I was struggling to do Oauth using dialogflow python library now I see we need to use google oauth library in order to do so. what's the use of bigquery here if I may ask? since I have already looked upon the link once and ignored it because of the same reason.

Comment: Did you check my answer about `google-auth-oauthlib` Python library usage and Oauth concepts?

Answer (score 0):

Exploring the comment being posted and looking into *OAuth 2.0* authentication [concept](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user) document, you can find nice [example](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user#authenticating_and_calling_the_api) for end user implementation related to Cloud Bigquery API, that can be smoothly transformed to be also applicable for Dialogflow API.

Using Python [google-auth-oauthlib](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, you might be requested to identify the *OAuth* scopes entitling the end-user to authenticate to the particular [Google Cloud API](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/overview) service. You can check out the reference [list](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#dialogflow) for available OAuth 2.0 Scopes, in particular for Dialogflow API move to this [chapter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#dialogflow).

Basically, [InstalledAppFlow()](https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google_auth_oauthlib.flow.html#google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow) class in the code example performs OAuth 2.0 *authentication/authorization* [action](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#basicsteps) using the appropriate user access token and inspecting the granted scopes.

Comment: alright Nick, I'll try the mentioned approach and will update accordingly. Thank you